# Two event listeners cancelling each other out - JS. Why?

Tags: javascript

I have an event listener on for a dropdown menu that works just fine:

JS

```
const selected = document.querySelectorAll(".selected");
const optionsContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".options-container");

for(let i = 0; i < selected.length; i++){
    selected[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
    optionsContainer[i].classList.toggle("open");
    selected[i].classList.toggle("open");
    for (let j = 0; j < selected.length; j++){
      if(i != j && selected[j].classList.contains("open")){
        optionsContainer[j].classList.toggle("open");
        selected[j].classList.toggle("open");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

However, now I also want to close the dropdown menu (which involves toggling optionsContainer and selected), when the user clicks outside the block. Of course this toggle is conditional on whether the dropdown menu is open as well. This is the JS I have come up with:

```
window.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  for(let i = 0; i < selected.length; i++){
    if(selected[i].classList.contains("open")){
      optionsContainer[i].classList.toggle("open");
      selected[i].classList.toggle("open");
    }
  } 
});
```

However, when I run the code with both of these, the first event listener does not execute either.

I think it might be because clicking on the menu also counts as clicking on the window, so you toggle twice and get no result. However, I'm still not sure...

Comment: try to add a mouse event argument to your listener and inspect its `target` element: `window.addEventListener("click", (event) => ...` and return from the callback if the target is `.selected`

Comment: @Andriy Sorry can you elaborate a bit more? I am still fairly new to the language :)

Comment: What I meant is that you can ignore clicks in your `window.addEventListener("click"...` listener if the click should be handled only by `selected[i].addEventListener("click"...` listener. To do it, you can inspect callback argument `event.target` or `event.path`. Please create a minimal STACKBLITZ reproduction if you need further help and I will try to help you there